# Are measurable functions almost surely constant on atoms?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space. A $\mu$-atom is an $A\in\Sigma$ such that $\mu(A)>0$ and for all $B\in\Sigma$ such that $B\subseteq A$, either $\mu(B)=\mu(A)$ or $\mu(B)=0$ holds.

Now let $(X,\mathcal{X})$ be a measurable space with the property that for all $x,y\in X$ there is $B\in\mathcal{X}$ such that $x\in B$ and $y\notin B$.

> Is every measurable function $f:\Omega\to X$ almost surely constant?
>   That is, is there for every $\mu$-atom $A\in\Sigma$ some point $x\in
>  X$ such that $f^{-1}\big(\{x\}\big)$ has $\mu$-outer measure $\mu(A)$?

It is not hard to prove that the answer is yes if $\mathcal{X}$ is generated by a countable family of sets, but the approach does not generalize.

*Motivation:* I face the problem in economic modelling. I want the agents to be represented by a probability space, where the atomic part represents "big" players. The behavior is given by a measurable function and want to ensure that the behavior of each big player is well defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Let $\Omega$ be an uncountable set, and $\Sigma$ the $\sigma$-algebra consisting of all countable and co-countable sets.  Let $\mu$ be the probability measure assigning measure 0 to all countable sets, and measure 1 to all co-countable sets.  Note every co-countable set is an atom.  Let $(X, \mathcal{X}) = (\Omega, \Sigma)$ (note that $\Sigma$ separates points), and let $f : \Omega \to \Omega$ be the identity function, which is certainly measurable.   Then for each $x$, $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is a singleton and hence has measure 0.

Indeed, we could replace $f$ with any bijection of $\Omega$.

Comment: Somehow I managed to oversee the most obvious example of a strange atom. Thank you!

Comment: I think you overlooked the example, but did not oversee it.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Thanks. English is not my native language, so that is quite helpful.